# Entry's instance count get increases in each and every scroll while adding it in Table View

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, tableview

Description
I have added Entry control inside the TableView with uneven rows, scroll the TableView top and bottom, checked the instance count by using Android profiler. For each and every scroll, the Entry's instance count get increased.

Steps to Reproduce
Add the Entry inside the Table view
Scroll the Table view
Check the Entry instance count by using Android profiler
Expected Behavior
Entry's instance count not get increased while scrolling

Actual Behavior
Entry's instance count increases on each scroll

Basic Information
Version with issue:
Last known good version: Checked in both 3.1.0.697729 and 4.0.0.497661
IDE: Visual Studio Professional 2017, Android Studio 3.4
Platform Target Frameworks:
Android: Android SDK version 6.0 (API 23)
Android Support Library Version: 28.0.0.1
Nuget Packages:
Affected Devices: MotoE2 (4G-LTE)

Screenshots:

Initial instance :
[image]

After 10 scrolls :
[image]

[Reproduction Link](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/files/3310658/TableViewIssue.zip)

Comment: What is your question?  Where is the relevant code?  Code needs to be posted in the body, not in a link to an external repo

Comment: You can download the sample from the link shared above.

Comment: please read [ask] and [mcve].